# Ising model with open boundary condition

Tags: ising-model

Can you give me any reference about solving 1 D Ising model with open boundary condition, magnetic field and nearest interaction?

Comment: It's a straightforward application of the transfer matrix formalism. What are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Finally I solved it. Thanks for comment.